# wagtail-transfer v0.9.1 I cannot see import pages as superuser

Tags: wagtail

wagtail-transfer v0.9.1 I cannot see import pages as superuser

I am trying wagtail-transfer on two local wagtail 4.2.2 instances, I have followed instructions, but cannot see import pages on action menu - pages menu ?

also I cannot see the import pages permission from the docs ie.

```
Create a user group (Wagtail admin > Settings > Groups > Add a group) with the permission "Can import pages and snippets from other sites". The "Import" menu item, and the associated import views, will only be available to members of this group (and superusers).
```

Comment: Okay I can see import user on left hand menu, and it works as superuser, but I need to add the group for other users

Comment: added the group with import pages perm and added user to group but they still cannot see import page in the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have not set the target sources you will not see the import button in the menu

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).